# Why has the 'to lowercase' shortcut been removed from VS2015?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

In previous versions of Visual Studio, you could make all selected text lowercase with CTRL+U, and all uppercase using CTRL+SHIFT+U.

The uppercase shortcut remains in the 2015 version of VS, the lowercase shortcut, however, has been removed.

Does anybody have any info regarding this?

I thought it may have been because it conflicted with a shortcut for newly introduced functionality which had to take priority, but the only CTRL+U shortcut relies on a previous combination of keys too.

Comment: No, works fine on my machine.  Use Tools > Customize > Keyboard to change key bindings.  The command name is Edit.MakeLowercase

Comment: The two shortcuts works fine on VS2019 v16.5.2

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I had the same issue because I have resharper installed which overwrites VS shortcut Ctrl+U

1. Instead of using the shortcut keys you can do it though menu (Edit -> Advanced -> Make Uppercase; Edit -> Advanced -> Make Lowercase) as you can see from the screenshot below that make upper has a shortcut while make lower doesn't!
   [image]
2. to fix this issue you can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Type "makelowercase" in show commands containing: to filter commands -> Edit.MakeLowercase -> Press shortcut keys -> Ctrl+U. did you notice the lowest most filed "Shortcut currently used by:" that's how I knew that resharper is what overwriting this vs shortcut.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165341.aspx

check the reference from the above link, you can see they are still using this shortcut for VS2015

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into an issue that might shed light on why this was removed.

The keystroke for uncommenting is ctrl + k + u, which I managed to screw up without noticing the effects until it was too late to ctrl + z it away.

I had to do a whole bunch of find/replace to repair the damage that ctrl + u allowed me to inflict on my code.